# How to get value from Json List - flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have this code where i get json data into a list in flutter but i don't really know how to get the particular data i want like the value

**main.dart**

```
 Future<String> loadDataFromJson() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString("assets/categories.json");
  }

  Future loadData() async {
    String jString = await loadDataFromJson();
    final jRes = json.decode(jString) as List;
    List<Category> datas = jRes.map((e) => Category.fromJson(e)).toList();
    print(datas);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }
```

Here I printed the data and it gave me this `I/flutter ( 6111): [Instance of 'Category', Instance of 'Category', Instance of 'Category', Instance of 'Category']`

**Models**

```
class Category {
  final String catId;
  final String catName;

  Category({this.catId, this.catName});

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Category(catId: json['cat_id'], catName: json['category']);
  }
}
```

my json is something like this but there are multiple

```
{
        "category": "Design & Creativity",
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_suncategory": [
            {
                "sub_name": "Ads",
                "sub_image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589838017489-9198a27bd040?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8YWR2ZXJ0aXNlbWVudHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
            }
        ]
    }
```

So please how do i get the value i want

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your problem but this may help you;

If your json values in 'jRes', you can do

```
String myCategory = jRes["category"];
String subName = jRes["cat_suncategory"][0]["sub_name"];
String subImage = jRes["cat_suncategory"][0]["sub_image"];
```

Because of using '[0]' is; the 'cat_suncategory' is an array and you should take first element of it, it means [0].